# Distinguish between JSON and other errors

Tags: json, go, error-handling

```
enc := json.NewEncoder(w)
err := enc.Encode(struct {
    Method    string        `json:"method"`
    Results   []interface{} `json:"results"`
    CacheTime int           `json:"cache_time"`
}{Method: answerInlineQueryMethod, Results: results, CacheTime: 0})
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("failed to answer to inline query: %s", err)
}
```

How can I distinguish between JSON errors, which should cause a panic and errors caused by sending the response, which should be logged?

Comment: Where is a "response" sent in your example code?

Comment: It's send to a``http.ResponseWriter``.

Comment: Please use `gofmt`. Your code is very difficult to read.

Comment: For an anonymous struct only to be JSON-encoded, a `map[string]interface{}` would be a more natural data type to use.

Answer (score 9):

The `encoding/json` package defines the error types it will return. For encoding you have [`MarshalerError`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#MarshalerError),
 [`UnsupportedTypeError`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#UnsupportedTypeError),
 and [`UnsupportedValueError`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#UnsupportedValueError).

You can inspect if the error type returned by `Encode` is one of these 3.

If the responses are not huge and don't rely on sending multiple json values per the `json.Encoder` protocol, you can simply use [`json.Marshal`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) and write the response separately.